# T-SQL: Query to get sqlserver.exe location

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I would like to get `sqlserver.exe` location using T-SQL query.

If there is something like:

```
select 
    InstanceDefaultDataPath = serverproperty('InstanceDefaultDataPath'),
    InstanceDefaultLogPath = serverproperty('InstanceDefaultLogPath')
```

but which will get us the running SQL Server location?

Comment: The things that are available via `ServerProperty()` are well documented. Do you see anything in that documentation that would give you this information? And why would that information be relevant in SQL?

Comment: @KenWhite Not anything relevant beside these 2 props. I thought there is some workaround how to obtain it.

Comment: FYI, the name of the executable is sqlservr.exe, not sqlserver.exe.

Comment: @DanGuzman Yep, know it, but thanks for correcting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just execute undocumented MS function ***xp_instance_regread*** to read the path from Windows registry:

```
DECLARE @folder NVARCHAR(4000)

EXEC master.dbo.xp_instance_regread
    N'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE',
    N'Software\Microsoft\MSSQLServer\Setup',
    N'SQLPath', 
    @folder OUTPUT

SELECT @folder + '\Binn'
```

Answer (score 0):

This works:

```
-- Location of sqlservr.exe
SELECT BinnFolder = SUBSTRING(s.filename, 2, f.sqlexe_filepos - 1)
FROM sys.dm_server_services s
    OUTER APPLY(SELECT sqlexe_filepos = CHARINDEX('\sqlservr.exe"', filename)) f
WHERE f.sqlexe_filepos > 0 -- skip other services
```